# Trying to using ng-select but get an error

Tags: angular, angular6

I recently learning angular-6 now i'm trying to use `ng-select` https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select . But i get an error

> ERROR in src/app/subject.service.ts(20,27): error TS2339: Property
>   'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

here is my `subject.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Course } from './course'
    import { CourseService } from  './course.service';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpEventType, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from,interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
    import { filter ,delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class SubjectService {

      constructor(private c_service:CourseService, private http:HttpClient) { }

      getCourse(term: string = null): Observable<Course[]> {
           let items = this.requestCourse();
           console.log(items);
             if (term) {
                items = items.filter(x => x.CourseId.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1);
            }
            return (items).pipe(delay(500));
        }

        requestCourse() {
          return  this.http.get<any>(`http://192.168.3.223:84/elearningapi/course_api.php?request=1`);
        }
    }
```

from this request `http://192.168.3.223:84/elearningapi/course_api.php?request=1` i get this

```
[  
   {  
      "CourseId":"C002",
      "CourseDescription":"Javascript"
   },
   {  
      "CourseId":"C003",
      "CourseDescription":"Math"
   },
   {  
      "CourseId":"C004",
      "CourseDescription":"English Language"
   },
   {  
      "CourseId":"C005",
      "CourseDescription":"IPS"
   },
   {  
      "CourseId":"C006",
      "CourseDescription":"IPA"
   },
   {  
      "CourseId":"C007",
      "CourseDescription":"C#"
   }
]
```

How can i fix it ? thanks in advance

Comment: whats the rxjs version

Comment: i'm using  "rxjs": "~6.2.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJs have changed the way you chain operators together in version 6. In the new version you pipe operators like map and filter before using them, like this:

```
items = items.pipe(filter(x => x.CourseId.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1));
```